# Is this the correct syntax for using the $stateProvider in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using this syntax for route providing but when choosing the `#/posts` route 
the code douse not run properly:

```
app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
 function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

   $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })

.state('posts', {
    url: '/posts/{id}',
    templateUrl: '/posts.html',
    controller: 'PostsCtrl'
})

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
 }])
```

Comment: Have you tried "#/posts/"  ? /posts is not mapeed

Comment: Yes I tried doing so and I managed to get my optimum result.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zVhkMGvtI7oGnlUGFPPD?p=preview)

The reason would be, that url `'/posts'` is in fact **not** mapped. There are few approaches, but the most typicall, I'd say, would be parent-child. So, we should introduce it as a parent (list view)

```
// this could/should be a state for all posts
.state('posts', {
    url: '/posts',
    templateUrl: '/posts.html',
    controller: 'PostsCtrl'
})
// this would be a child state, when id is provided
.state('posts.detail', {
    url: '/{id}',
    templateUrl: '/post.detail.html',
    controller: 'PostsDetailCtrl'
})
```

Also, the parent template `posts.html` must contain some target for its detail view `<div ui-view="">`